# Show / hide password using JSF / PrimeFaces is not working

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

```
          form i {
            margin-left: -25px;
            margin-top: 11px;
            cursor: pointer;
          }
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />

            <p:inputText id="productadminpassword" required="true"
                value="#{ApplicationManagedBean24.saveRequestMap['Object::MasterPassword']}"
                styleClass="inputField border" style="width:300px;"
                requiredMessage="Admin Password is mandatory"
                type="password">
                <p:ajax event="change" process="@this"
                    update="@([id$=Adminpasswordcheck]) @([id$=prodeletepassword])"
                    onstart="AdminpasswordMessageRemove();" />  
            </p:inputText>
            
         <i class="bi bi-eye-slash" id="togglePassword"></i>

         <script type="text/javascript">
const togglePassword = document.querySelector('#togglePassword');
const password = document.querySelector('#productadminpassword');

togglePassword.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const type = password.getAttribute('type') === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
    password.setAttribute('type', type);
    this.classList.toggle('bi-eye');
});
</script>
```

These are i have done. Eye(eye-slash) icon is rendered, but it is not working and input text also remains hidden. I also tried new toggle feature in password tag. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the PrimeFaces `p:password` component with the `toggleMask` attribute set to `true`. This attribute will add a show/hide icon to the password to allow the password to be unmasked/remasked. So:

```html
<p:password value="#{bean.password}" toggleMask="true"/>
```

See the showcase for a demo https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/password.xhtml

See also https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/components/password

Comment: Hi @Jasper, I really appreciate your contribution, but i need to use inputText component only. Kindly suggest any other ways or alteration of code.

Comment: Sorry, but this is my answer. I don't see any reason why one would want to do this any other way.